# Avoid duplicates in postgresql database after scraping with beautifull soup

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping god names from the website of a game. The scraped text is stored in a postgresql database through Django models. 
When I run my program twice, I get everything double. 
How do I avoid this?

```
import requests
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import psycopg2
import os
import django
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'locallibrary.settings'
django.setup()
from scraper.models import GodList
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://www.smitegame.com/'
content = session.get(url, verify=False).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
allgods = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'god'})

allitem = []

for god in allgods:
    godName = god.find('p')
    godFoto = god.find('img').get('src')
    allitem.append((godName, godFoto))
    GodList.objects.create(godName=godName.text)
```

below my models file.

```
class GodList(models.Model):
    godName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    godFoto = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.godName
```

Comment: You can make **godName** field as Unique in database.

Comment: I added unique = True in my models. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Please check godName in table before inserting that might solve your issue. **if not GodList.objects.filter(godName=godName.text):
        GodList.objects.create(godName=godName.text)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `get_or_create()` method on the model manager instead of `create()` to avoid adding a duplicate.

```py
god, created = GodList.objects.get_or_create(godName=godName.text)
```

`god` will obviously be the model instance that was gotten or created, and `created` will be returned as `True` if the object had to be created else `False`.

Comment: After some errors and looking up the documentation of Django, this worked perfectly! Thanks